# Chain of any number of Observable::flatMap calls

Tags: rx-java2

Let's say I have a few `Observable` suppliers with the side effect on `get` call:

```
Subject<String> firstSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> firstSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of first one");
    return firstSubject;
};

Subject<String> secondSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> secondSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of second one");
    return secondSubject;
};

Subject<String> thirdSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> thirdSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of third one");
    return thirdSubject;
};
```

Now I want to combine them in the following way - the `get` of the next supplier is called after the `Observable` from previous one emits a value (`onNext` is called).
I can do it with the following code:

```
firstSupplier.get()
        .flatMap(__ -> secondSupplier.get())
        .flatMap(__ -> thirdSupplier.get())
        .subscribe();
// output: side effect of first one
firstSubject.onNext("");
// output: side effect of second one
secondSubject.onNext("");
// output: side effect of third one
```

How can I rewrite this code to accept unknown number of suppliers, passed as a - for example - `Collection<Supplier<Observable>>`?

I've reviewed various factory methods of `Observable` (like `merge`, `concat`), however they all are taking a collection of `ObservableSource`, which means I have to call `get` on all of my suppliers eagerly. However in my case it is important to call it lazily - only after previous `Observable` emits a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

I completely forgot that `Observable.flatMap` calls the mapper even if `maxConcurrency` is set to 1 and queues up the generated `Observable`s to be run later.

I hope the following setup works as expected (i.e, it wasn't specified what should happen to the subsequent `onNext`s to the subjects).

```java
Subject<String> firstSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> firstSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of first one");
    return firstSubject;
};

Subject<String> secondSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> secondSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of second one");
    return secondSubject;
};

Subject<String> thirdSubject = PublishSubject.create();
Supplier<Observable<String>> thirdSupplier = () -> {
    System.out.println("side effect of third one");
    return thirdSubject;
};

Collection<Supplier<Observable<String>>> collection =
    Arrays.asList(firstSupplier, secondSupplier, thirdSupplier);

Observable.fromIterable(collection)
.concatMap(supplier -> supplier.get().take(1))
.subscribe();

System.out.println("// output: side effect of first one");
firstSubject.onNext("");
System.out.println("// output: side effect of second one");
secondSubject.onNext("");
System.out.println("// output: side effect of third one");
```

prints:

```
side effect of first one
// output: side effect of first one
side effect of second one
// output: side effect of second one
side effect of third one
// output: side effect of third one
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem. With this solution, `get` methods of all suppliers from the collection is called even if none of `Observable` emits an item.
I other words - I don't want `get` of `second` supplier to be called before I call `onNext` on the `Subject` returned from `first` supplier.
(btw. I've edited the question since your answer, because there was a mistake - instead of `onComplete` I meant `onNext`).

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Still, all the suppliers are invoked before any of the `Observable` emits a first value. I've added logging to the each `get`method: `Supplier<Observable> first = () -> {
            System.out.println("first::get");
            return PublishSubject.create();
        };`
And the output is: `first::get, second::get, third::get` which means, that all of them were called, even without calling `onNext` on the subjects.

Comment: First, did you leave out the `/* maxConcurrency: */ 1` part? Second, what you are describing is impossible: to know to call `get()`, something has to observer the subject returned by the `get()`!

Comment: I've tried both with and without the `maxConcurency` parameter - the same result.

Comment: If your suppliers create the `PublishSubject`s, how do you signal `onNext` on any of them from the outside?

Comment: In the question I've simplified implementation. In the reality it returns the `Subject` created somewhere else.

Comment: If subjects exist already, why not have a collection of subjects, why the supplier indirection?

Comment: Again, this was just a simplification to make the question cleaner. In reality, the `get` method of the supplier has a side effect. And that is the reason why it is so important for me to call it in the appropriate moment.

Comment: Please provide a more representative example as your simplified version doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've edited the question to better show the problem.

Comment: Updated my answer again.